# Getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException error when loading the XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Im getting System.UnauthorizedAccessException everytime. Im running it as adminstrator. But Its still gives error... Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Test\\" + textBox1.Text;
doc.Load(path); //Getting error
```

Thanks.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied to path 'C:\Users\x\Documents\Test\Hello'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**

use [Path.Combine(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_)

> Combines two strings into a path.

**Example**

```
var myDocs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

var dir = Path.Combine(myDocs,"Test");
var fileName =Path.Combine(dir, textBox1.Text); 

Debug.WriteLine(fileName);

doc.Load(fileName)
```

**Secondly**

look at the documentation

[XmlDocument.Load Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Load_System_String_)

> `UnauthorizedAccessException`  filename specified a file that is
>   read-only.

Double check your `path` it doesn't look like a filename. If it is a file without an extension (and it does exist), make sure its not read-only

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied to path
>
> '**C:\Users\x\Documents\Test\Hello**'.

If you correct that you'll probably win

Comment: *Your problem is your path isn't even a file name its a directory* it can be a file without an extension. You can't make that statement without seeing the result of a `dir` statement.

Comment: @Saruman thanks. It's worked perfect. Also its my bad too, I forgot to change something in code. I read your answer and it was helpful.